# How to get value from another method?How to take value from another method and use it in the main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, methods, contacts

I want the phonenumber to be loaded into "String xx"...how is it possible?The phone number(taken from contacts) gets displayed in the edit text given...But i want to load the same number into the String xx in the main activity..

```
public class MsgcontactActivity extends Activity {

private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) 
{  
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  
}

EditText phoneTxt;
TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String xx=phoneTxt.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), xx,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
{  
     String phone="";
     Cursor contacts=null;
     try
     {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {  
            switch (requestCode) 
            {  
                case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:  
                    Uri result = data.getData();
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment(); 
                    contacts=getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },  null);
                    int phoneIdx = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA); 
                    if (contacts.moveToFirst()) 
                    {
                       phone = contacts.getString(phoneIdx);  
                       EditText phoneTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
                       phoneTxt.setText(phone);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {  
                       Toast.makeText(this, "error", 100).show();
                    }  
                    break;  
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Warning: activity result not ok",50).show();
            }  
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {  
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 50).show();  
        } 
        finally 
        {  
            if (contacts != null) 
            {  
                contacts.close();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Xml Used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:id="@+id/phoneno"  
    android:inputType="text|phone"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Contacts"  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:id="@+id/Contacts"  
    android:text="Contacts"  
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:onClick="doLaunchContactPicker"/>
<TextView 
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/phoneno" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Comment: declare xx as a class variable and write "xx = phone" after PhoneTxt.setText(phone). But you won't be able to use it in onCreate. Create a private method instead.

Comment: Why cant i use it in oncreate?? i want to use it specifically use in oncreate......So i can pass it to next activity

Comment: because by the time you get anything in your EditText, i.e. response from your picker, the oncreate code has already been executed. SO it'd be better if you set the xx value after you get the response.\